# Vampires in space

Tags: space-travel, spaceships, vampires

The setting is our Earth of today (2018) with one difference: some Space Agency decided to go back the Moon and built a ship that is ready to depart, using today's technology.

For *reasons*, the crew of this mission is made of vampires and the Space Agency is fully aware of the fact, though it was kept secret from the public.

The vampires are quite classical:

- They must drink blood regularly to survive,
- They burn in the light of the sun,
- They are pale,
- They have the fangs to bite.

How do the Space Agency in question build the ship to ensure that the vampires can go the Moon and back safely?

Assume an Apollo 11-type mission, with a landing planned on the side of the Moon that is not under direct sunlight. That way they can go out and enjoy 1/6th of Earth gravity while they do some scientific research, and also some shenanigans for TV.

Comment: I don't see how this would change much.. wouldn't you just apply a bunch of coatings to the interior of the suits and spaceship that block any rays that are harmful to the vampire? Like super sunglasses? Its not like your astronauts where walking around with their skin exposed in the first place.

Comment: If you're going the "burn in the light of the sun" route for vampires (nothing wrong with that) instead of the truly classical they lose their powers in daylight, then you have your vampires potentially spontaneously combusting whenever sunlight hits them. The earth's atmosphere protects us from many of the sun's more dangerous effects - in space there is no such protection.

Comment: Is this Mr. Musk revealing some details about *who* bought those tickets for the [first BFR trip to the moon](https://arstechnica.com/science/2018/09/spacex-says-its-bfr-will-fly-someone-around-the-moon-we-have-questions)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Direct sunlight in space is already harmful hence why the heavy tinting on spacesuits and windows.

You don't need any real modifications except maybe heavier tinting on the windows but maybe not even that.

The real advantage is that you can remove the life support systems such as oxygen tanks, CO2 scrubbers and radiation shielding saving a massive amount of weight. If you fill the craft with nitrogen, you can also remove the fire suppression systems.

You still need spacesuits so they can talk and to stop them from freezing as night time can hit -173c which will freeze them solid and during the day (with tinted helmets) it will hit 127c. Forget walking around without suits. Without gas to carry soundwaves, they can't communicate so no "one small step for a vampire" speech.

Comment: How about using sign language?

Comment: Sign language isn't very exciting to watch on TV

Comment: @Renan Also, you need direct line of sight for sign language, which is cumbersome in a space suit or small spaces such as the ones found in a (non-Galaxy Class) space ship.

Answer (score 3):

Remove windows from the ship and use cameras and screens instead. Replace food with blood bags and land on the...

[image: dark side of the moon]

And justify the leeches by experimenting whether the undead can walk on the moon without space suits.

Last but not least, this will be the inspiration for the best psychobilly album ever.

Comment: Well, the dark side of the moon isn't more dark then the other. Sunlight hits it the same way. It is just pointing away from earth, so people here can't see it.

Comment: @MartinScharrer That does not sound correct at all. Clearly the moon, too, must have roughly half of it averted from the sun, just like the earth, since both are round. There should be a difference as great as day and night. Literally.

Comment: @Suthek Yes it does but the phrase "dark side of the moon" doesn't refer to the night side of the moon where it is literally dark but the side that we can't send direct radio signals to, the side facing away from Earth, I believe it's because missions to the moon go "radio dark" during that part of their orbit.

Comment: As ever when I see these posts on the review queue I'm torn between applauding them for the funnies and slapping them down for taking the mickey

Comment: @Ash -- but this response does have the unusual property of actually having answered the query.

Comment: @elemtilas Yeah this time, and you're right that's not a given, but the tongue and cheek note is not, to me, useful.

Comment: @Suthek: Yes, that's what I meant. "Sunlight hits it the same way" was meant as "as often as", not "get's sunlight at the same time". Some people think "the dark side of the moon" means that that side is always dark (and therefore save for vampires) but it gets the same amount of sunlight as the side facing earth. Ash comment about "radio dark" however, makes also sense.